# In destination module, how do you save returned value from exported module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am exporting a simple function that returns the data passed into a function expression. In another node module I am using the imported function and passing in the params. I am calling this function in a router.post -->.then(csv=> grid.dataObj(csv));

See below for where I call the function

```js
router.post('/csvjson', upload.single('csv'), function(req, res) {
  const sampleFile = req.file.buffer.toString('utf8');
  csv({
      output: "json"
    })
    .fromString(sampleFile)
    .then((csvRow) => {
      grid.dataObj(csvRow);  //THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE FUNCTION
      res.json(JSON.stringify(csvRow));
    })
})
```

This is where I actually export the function

```js
var dataObj = function(el) {
  return el;
}

   module.exports={ dataObj }
```

So my question, shouldn't this pass the data to the module and save the variables in dataObj? so I can use that in any calculation?

Comment: 1. `shouldn't this [...] save the variables in dataObj` How do you mean? `dataObj` is your function, why would anything get saved in it? 2. the function currently returns the passed data as-is, but when you are calling it, you're discarding the returned value anyway. `grid.dataObj(csvRow);` does absolutely nothing to `csvRow`.

Comment: `dataObj` is the function you are calling, and all it does is return the value that is passed in to it. If you want to save its return value you need to saying something like `var k = dataObj('k')`. Also if you are calling the imported module `grid` when you require it, the syntax would be `var k = grid('k')` and not `grid.dataObj('k')`

Comment: @ChrisG so how would I actually go about saving the value in dataObj so i can use it in the other module?

Comment: Again, `dataObj` is a *function*. "saving the value in dataObj" doesn't make *any* sense. Do you want to save data in the *grid* module?

Comment: As @ChrisG said, the **value** of `dataObj` is a function. What you meant to ask was *how do I save the return value of `dataObj` to a variable*

Comment: @ChrisG yes I want to save the value in grid module (where dataObj function resides)

Comment: Right, you can do it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/kkzn29xq6v

Comment: @ChrisG this works if I do getData  in the module where I import grid. But I want to access the variable inside the grid module itself. Is there way to pass the variable back?

Comment: You can call `grid.getData()` from any other module, and you can simply use `data` inside the module, in some other function. I guess the latter is what you mean by "access the variable inside the grid module itself"? I still don't understand what exactly your issue is. Why do you want to "pass the variable back?" Pass back *where*?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a basic class structure similar to this

```
function Grid() {
  this.data = null;
}

Grid.prototype.saveData = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
}

module.exports = Grid;
```

Then you can require it into another file like: `var grid = require('./Grid.js');`

Next, call the function `grid.saveData("This is some data")`

Finally, you can see the new value by saying `console.log(grid.data)`